# Get JSON keys with values

Tags: java, json

I have been trying to get the key and value of my JSONObject. I have no idea why this isn't working, because String key is clearly a string?

My code:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(historie2.getData());
            Iterator<?> keys = obj.keys();

            while(keys.hasNext()) {
                String key = (String)keys.next();
                String value =  obj.getString(key); //This is where the error comes

            }
```

The JSONObject:

```
{
    "relatie_website": ["www.apple.com"],
    "relatie_kvknummer": ["NL3234234"],
    "relatie_naam": ["Apple international inc."],
    "relatie_d400code": [null],
    "relatie_zoeknaam": ["APPLE INC"],
    "relatie_debiteurnummer": ["3523523"],
    "relatie_btwnummer": ["332342"]
}
```

This is the error I have been getting:

> org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["relatie_website"] not a string.

Comment: `["www.apple.com"]` is a 1-element array and not a string.

Comment: You objects are arrays and not strings, you need to remove the [] from the values

Comment: Oh wow, thanks for the heads up guys! *facepalm*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your object to be sth like that :

```
    {
    "relatie_website": "www.apple.com",
    "relatie_kvknummer": "NL3234234",
    "relatie_naam": "Apple international inc.",
    "relatie_d400code": null,
    "relatie_zoeknaam": "APPLE INC",
    "relatie_debiteurnummer": "3523523",
    "relatie_btwnummer": "332342"
}
```

Because the problem is that your values are an array and not a string.

But if you need te keep your values in an array you can change your code to support the arrays :

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(historie2.getData());
            Iterator<?> keys = obj.keys();

            while(keys.hasNext()) {
                String key = (String)keys.next();
                JSONArray value =  obj.getJSONArray(key); 

            }
```

And you will have a JsonArray that you can manipulate as you want by doing sth like that :

```
for (int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++) {
    String val = value.getString(i).toString();
    logger.info("val : " + val);
}
```